# Detect html tag on a string, get the value and remove values inside html tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, html

I have a String which contains HTML tags:

```
var str = "Hello World <br><p>1</p><em>My First Javascript</em>";
```

And i also have a form with hidden input:

```
<input type='hidden' name='id' value=''>
```

With that String above, i want to get the value inside `<p>` tag which is `1` and assign that value to hidden input. And after that, i wanted to remove all the HTML tag inside the string which are these `<br><p>1</p><em>My First Javascript</em>`. So therefore the only value of `str` will be `Hello World`.

Is there any way how to do this on Javascript or jquery?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do this using JavaScript or jQuery, but what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, what you want to be doing is to convert your string into a jQuery object.  You can do so like this -

```
var str = "Hello World <br><p>1</p><em>My First Javascript</em>";
var $holder = $('<div>');
$holder.append(str);
```

Now we have your string encapsulated within another div element.  Next we extract the value within the `<p>` element -

```
var value = $holder.find('p').text(); // 1
```

Now that we have that value we can place it into the hidden input field -

```
$('input[name="id"]').val(value);
```

Now to remove all other elements from the original string - we'll use the container we created earlier for this -

```
$.each($holder.children(),function(index,elem){
  $(elem).remove();
});
```

Now we can take the textual contents of `$holder` with `$holder.text()` and it should be just -

> Hello World

---

If you would like to fiddle with this,
you can do so here - http://jsfiddle.net/TVXbw/1/

Comment: Wow! You sir is a genius... this is very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: No problem friend - Glad to help...  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a quick and simple way:

```
var tmpDiv = document.createElement('div');
tmpDiv.innerHTML = str;//where str is the html string, obviously...
var pTagValue = tmpDiv.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;//=== '1'
document.getElementById('yourInputId').value = pTagValue;
```

If I understood correctly, that's what you're after, right?

Comment: Half way - what about emptying the contents of the original `str` down to only `"Hello World"`?

Comment: just use the `childNodes[0].textContent`, the `childNodes` nodelist (!== Array) returns both html elements and textnodes, if an element of this list hast the propery `textContent`, you're dealing with... text, that isn't contained in any sort of special tag